# How to simulate wind speed in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic, modeling, agent-based-modeling, systemdynamics

I have created a Wind Farm using [this tutorial](https://anylogic.help/tutorials/turbine-maintenance/index.html). Now I want to simulate the wind speed and simulate the turbine is going off due to heavy wind. I found [this research paper](https://www.anylogic.com/upload/iblock/252/252f819457ed26290021c78587aafe91.pdf) which describes about the components of the wind simulator and the logic behind it. But I don't have any idea how can I do this in AnyLogic. Do we want to use System Dynamic for wind speed simulation? Could you please provide me a direction how can I start developing this wind speed simulator? I am going to select the **2.1 Slow Component** in this paper.

Thank you!

Comment: the paper proposes many wind modeling methodologies depending on the application... choose one and ask again

Comment: @Felipe I am going to implement the "Slow Component" as the wind simulator. I updated the question

Comment: Hey, best avoid asking open-ended "how do I" questions on SOF. LinkedIn forum would be a better place, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community